# jquery press key twice

Tags: jquery, key

Here is the html code with all included (css/js)
The mouse events are working fine. The only issue I am facing is that
it is needed to press twice a key (and kind like a double-click, i.e. very
fast for the expected behaviour to happen). What am I doing wrong here?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    img {
        width:  960px;
        height: 655px;
        margin-bottom: 10px; 
    }

        html {
            max-width: 100%;

        }

    body {
            padding: 0;
            margin-top: 10px;
            border-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            border-bottom: 0px;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
    </style> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="smiley.ico"></link>
</head>

<body>
    <IMG SRC="foto001.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto002.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto003.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto004.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto005.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto006.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto007.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto008.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto009.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto010.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto011.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto012.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto013.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto014.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto015.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto016.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto017.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto018.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto019.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto020.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto021.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto022.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto023.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto024.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto025.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto026.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto027.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto028.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto029.jpg" />
    <IMG SRC="foto030.jpg" />

    <script>

    var puloSeta = 9;    // 9 pixels

        // verifies mouse events
    var clicked = false, clickY;
        $(document).on({
            'mousemove': function(e) {
                clicked && updateScrollPos(e);
            },
            'mousedown': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
                clicked = true;
                clickY = e.pageY;
            },
            'mouseup': function() {
                clicked = false;
                $('html').css('cursor', 'auto');
            }
        });

        var updateScrollPos = function(e) {
            $('html').css('cursor', 'grabbing');
            $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + (clickY - e.pageY));
        }

    // idleTime counts the time the system is idle
    idleTime = 0;
        idleTimeKeyUp = 0; 

        minhamatriz = [    0,   
                         665,  1330,  1995,  2660,  3325, 
                3990,  4655,  5320,  5985,  6650, 
                7315,  7980,  8645,  9310,  9975,
               10640, 11305, 11970, 12635, 13300,
               13965, 14630, 15295, 15960, 16625,
               17290, 17955, 18620, 19285        ];

    $(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
            // Handles the idle timer on mouse wheel movement
        idleTime = -2.0;            
        });

        // Increment the idle time counter every minute.
        var myVar = setInterval(timerIncrement, 100); // some time      

    $(document).ready(function () {

    // Handles the idle timer on mouse clicks
    $(this).mousedown (function (e)  { idleTime =  -5000000; });
    $(this).mouseup   (function (e)  { idleTime =  0; });

    // Handles the idle timer on keypress movement.
        $(this).keypress(function (e)  { 

                            //idleTimeKeyUp = 0; 


                if (e.keyCode == 36) { // Home key
                                e.preventDefault();
                                $('body').addClass('.stop-scrolling');
                                $(window).scrollTop(0);
                                $('body').removeClass('.stop-scrolling');
                            }
                            else if (e.keyCode == 35) { // End key
                                e.preventDefault();
                            $('body').addClass('.stop-scrolling');
                                $(window).scrollTop($(document).height());
                                $('body').removeClass('.stop-scrolling');
                        }
                if (e.keyCode == 36 && e.which == 0) { // Home key
                                e.preventDefault();
                                $('body').addClass('.stop-scrolling');
                                $(window).scrollTop(0);
                        $('body').removeClass('.stop-scrolling');
                        }
                else if (e.keyCode == 35 && e.which == 0){ // End key
                $('body').addClass('.stop-scrolling');
                $("html, body").scrollTop($(document).height());
                e.preventDefault();
                $('body').removeClass('.stop-scrolling');
                        }
                            else if (e.keyCode == 38 && e.which == 0) {  // Up-arrow key
                                idleTimeKeyUp = -1;
                                $('body').addClass('.stop-scrolling');
                                e.preventDefault(); // essential to avoid default handler 
                                var top = $(window).scrollTop();
                                $(window).scrollTop(top - puloSeta);  
                                $('body').removeClass('.stop-scrolling');
                                puloSeta = 45; 
                            }
                            else if (e.keyCode == 40 && e.which == 0) {  // Dn-arrow key
                                idleTimeKeyUp = -1;
                                $('body').addClass('.stop-scrolling');                          
                                e.preventDefault(); // Essential to avoid default handler
                                var top = $(window).scrollTop();
                                $(window).scrollTop(top + puloSeta); 
                                $('body').removeClass('.stop-scrolling');
                                puloSeta = 45; 
                            }
                            else if (e.keyCode == 104 || e.which == 104) { // "h" key pressed
                                e.preventDefault();
                                alert("posicion en pixeles: " + $(window).scrollTop());
                                //return false;
                            }  
                            else if (e.keyCode == 0 && e.which == 91) {  // "[" pressed
                                $('body').addClass('.stop-scrolling');                                
                                e.preventDefault();
                                var y = $(window).scrollTop();
                                $(window).scrollTop(y-1);
                                $('body').removeClass('.stop-scrolling');                                
                                //return false;
                            }
                            else if (e.keyCode == 0 && e.which == 93) {  // "]" pressed
                                $('body').addClass('.stop-scrolling');
                                e.preventDefault();
                                var y = $(window).scrollTop();
                                $(window).scrollTop(y+1);
                                $('body').removeClass('.stop-scrolling');
                                //return false;
                            }
                else {
                idleTime = -5000000; 
                //$('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: posicaoFinal }, 150);
                }

    });

        $(this).keydown (function (e)  { 
            idleTime = -5000000; 
            //var myVar = setInterval(timerIncrement, 100); // some time        
            //clearInterval(myVar);
        });

    $(this).keyup   (function (e)  { idleTime = idleTimeKeyUp; puloSeta = 9; });
    });

        function timerIncrement() {
            idleTime = idleTime + 1;
            if (idleTime >= 4) { // some user defined time
            processing();            }
        }

    function processing() {
        var posicao = document.body.scrollTop;
        var posicaoFinal = valorcerto(minhamatriz, posicao);
        //old version, without animate
            //$("html, body").scrollTop(posicaoFinal);

            $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: posicaoFinal }, 120);
            if (posicaoFinal >= posicao) {
                $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: posicaoFinal+1 }, 120);
            }    

    }

    function valorcerto(matriz, laposicion) {
        if (matriz.indexOf(laposicion) != -1) {
            // position is located inside the array
        return parseInt(laposicion);
        }
        var fim = matriz.length-1;
        for (i=0; i<fim; i++) {
            var limiteA = matriz[i];
        var limiteB = matriz[i+1];
        if (laposicion > limiteA && laposicion < limiteB) {
            // position between limiteA and limiteB
            var diffA = laposicion - limiteA;
            var diffB = limiteB - laposicion;
            if (diffA == diffB) {
                // position is equidistant to both points
            return parseInt(laposicion);
            }
            if (diffA < diffB) {
            // position is closer to limiteA
            return parseInt(limiteA);
            }
                    else {
            // position is closer to limiteB
            return parseInt(limiteB);
                    }           
                }
        }
    }

    </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to this:

https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

basically:

```
//do something like this
$(this).on("dblclick", function(){});
```

OR

```
$(this).dblclick(function(){});
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough. The events which are not working as expected are the keyboard ones. I have just referred to mouse double-click event as an analogy. When I press the keys 'home, end, page up, page down' just once is like as if I haven't pressed any of them at all.

Comment: Is that even possible? I mean those keys are bit special, unlike character keys. Did you try assigning it to other keys to test whether the code works?